# import() use static string work well but string variable not work.And throwing error "Error: Cannot find module 'xxx module path'"

Tags: javascript, dynamic, import

Using static import mode works well.For example:

```
import App from './App.js';
```

And in common general style of using "import()" works well:

```
async function fun(){
    const App = async ()=> await import("./App.js");
    console.log(await App() )//it load module successfully
}
fun();
```

When i use a string variable parameter for import(),it dosn't work.And it will throw error:

```
async function fun(){
    const path = "./App.js";
    const App = async ()=> await import(path).catch(err=>console.log(err));
    await App() //Error: Cannot find module 'xxx module path'
}
fun();
```

So,i must load all modules before using.Could i dynamic import modules like that demo?

I go through the mdn [docs about dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) but not get helpful information.

And require() performs the same.

Does someone have the same questions?

Comment: So is it `"./App.js"` or `"../App.js"`? Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Amend the URL accordingly.

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT Thanks for your suggests,but how may i do for the fault.Need I delete the question and publish it again？

Comment: Why would you want to post this question again? Have you tried debugging this as suggested?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh,I am newer in stackoverflow .If you have suggestions.I am willing to kown and learn how to use it.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I post a doubt about it.And i read your suggestion about [debugging capabilities](https://ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a).But i don't kown how to do.I have a fault about posting question again,it will trouble others ,but how may i do for the fault?Shold I delete the question and republish it?

Comment: No! Again, just look at the Network tab. What URL do you see? Does this URL exist? If not, then change it accordingly. Please do not repost your questions.

Comment: Sorry,I can't understand about "Does this URL exist?".Shell i open the chrome browser devtools and look at the netwrok tab?Why do i see it and what should i change?

Comment: Oh,your mean is that i should update the url of question after edited?@SebastianSimon

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ./ and not ../, as ../ is the parent directory and not the current directory. I don't know why this only applies to dynamic imports, but thats just some weird thing about it.

Comment: Actually according to VSC auto complete it should apply to the second code you posted too, but for some weird reason it also works for me. But just replace ../ with ./ and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for watching this question and your suggest.I modify the code.Believe me,it's just a spell matter while keying in.My doubt also exists.

Comment: Thanks for your suggests,but how may i do for the fault.Need I delete the question and publish it again？ @GoldenretriverYT